# What can be said about $a_n\ $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, logarithms, exponential-function

> Let $\{a_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers such that $\exp(za_n) \to w$ where $z,w \in \mathbb C \setminus \{0\}.$ Then can we conclude that the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ is convergent?

I am trying to apply suitable logarithmic branch and exploit the continuity of that branch to conclude something about the convergence of the given sequence but the problem is that $\log \exp \neq \text {id}.$ Any help in this regard would be warmly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Rabin.

Comment: @Jo Jomax$:$ Could you please explain why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So this only needs to be true for one $z$?

Comment: What if $a_n= (2\pi_i n)/z$

Comment: @podiki$:$ $a_n$'s are positive reals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about $z=2i\pi$, $a_n=n$ and $\omega=1$ ?

Comment: If for all $z \in \mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ it holds (i.e. $\exp (za_n)$ converges to some non-zero limit) then we can certainly conclude that the given sequence is convergent. Am I right? Because then we can simply take $z$ to be any non-zero real number and as a result $w$ would necessarily be a non-zero real number (since the real line is complete) and then we can exploit the continuity and invertibility of the real logarithm to conclude.

Comment: Yes indeed. You would get that $\exp(a_n)$ converges to a limit $\omega$, and hence $(a_n)$ would converge to $\log(\omega)$.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Take $z = i$ and $a_n = 2n\pi$.  Then we have $e^{za_n}$ is a constant, but clearly $a_n$ does not converge.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: If for all $z \in \mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ it holds (i.e. $\exp(za_n)$ converges to some non-zero limit) then we can certainly conclude that the given sequence is convergent. Am I right? Because then we can simply take $z$ to be any non-zero real number and as a result $w$ would necessarily be a non-zero real number (since the real line is complete) and then we can exploit the continuity and invertibility of the real logarithm to conclude.